# cv2.VideoCapture directory of images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I though this would be simple, but i have been caught by the simplest of puzzles which i can't find the answer to anywhere,
I have some code which reads images and then OpenCV looks for differences.
I read files with the following command

```
vs = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/andrew/images/image_%6d.jpg")
```

and this work perfectly with images called image_000000.jpg image_000001.jpg
However i don't want to rename my images so i would like to read files called
MDAlarm_20180921-031140.jpg whcih contain the date then time.
What is the printf format for this ? as what ever I try it does not work i.e no files found or do the files need to start from 0 , so i need to append an index 
 starting at 000000?

Lastly once i have this working how can i tell which file is being processed ?
Many Thanks
Andrew

Comment: If you are on a decent OS (Linux or macOS), you could create symbolic links to your files quite simply.

Comment: I'm developing on ubuntu, and i don't see how links of tens of thousands of files would work very well. Hence I want to change my code to read the files in their source filename format.

Comment: `VideoCapture` with a sequence of images only works for images that are numbered consecutively starting at 0. It's intended as a convenience. Since your images aren't numbered like that, it's no longer a convenient to use `VideoCapture`. Simply use `glob` to get a list of files, sort it if necessary, and read the frames with `imread` in a loop.

Comment: You can write a 2-line script to generate the links, or remove them all, or re-generate them. You can use `readlink()` in your program to get the original filename.

Comment: probably there are good directory listing functions in python. Just try to imread the found files then.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, looks like i have to look at another route.